# Update listview from multiple threads in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, listview

I have a program where I want to populate a listview using multithreading.

But I have a problem where the ui thread cant update the listview fast enough.

When it runs the `checkWishList` sub I get `listview1.Items.count = 0`.

I tried with tasks using `task.waitall(tasks)`, I tried with `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll`, but that runs in a separate thread too, so i got an error trying to update ui it.

The only thing I got working is

```
Do Until (tasks(0).Status = 5 And tasks(0).Status = 5)
Application.DoEvents()
Loop
```

However this seems like a pretty bad solution and not a real fix.

So my question is, is there is any way to wait on running `checkWishList()` until the ui thread has finished updating, or can I get the `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll` to run in the ui thread?

Or should I have the threads fill a list of listviewitems, rather than call the uithread with invoke to add items, and then have the listview connecting to that datasource? Would that let the ui thread update faster?

Or run a foreach on the list and add them to the listview from the ui thread?

There is going to be about 30-50 records showing, but the searching for those records is what takes time, so that's why I want it done in multiple threads.

Of course, I could have the checkWishList DB query before adding the listviewitem and set the color straight away, but as I want other functions to call this sub also it means i would have to use the same code in multiple places, making future updates /changes more problematic.

I am using .net framework 4.5.

```
Private Delegate Sub ListViewAddItem_delegate(ByVal Col1 As String, ByVal Col2 As String, ByVal Col3 As String, ByVal Col4 As String, ByVal Col5 As String, ByVal col6 As String, ByVal col7 As String, ByVal col8 As String)
Private Sub ListViewAddItem(ByVal Col1 As String, ByVal Col2 As String, ByVal Col3 As String, ByVal Col4 As String, ByVal Col5 As String, ByVal col6 As String, ByVal col7 As String, ByVal col8 As String)
    If Me.listview1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New ListViewAddItem_delegate(AddressOf ListViewAddItem)
        Me.listview1.BeginInvoke(d, {Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, col6, col7, col8})
    Else
        listview1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, col6, col7, col8}))
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub search()
    listview1.Items.Clear()

    'Dim tasks = New Task(1) {}
    'For i As Integer = 0 To 1
            'if i = 0 then
                           'tasks(i) = Task.Run(AddressOf doSearch)
    'elseif i = 1 then
                            'tasks(i) = Task.Run(AddressOf doOtherSearch)
    'end if
    'Next
    'Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, Sub()
    '                                        Debug.Print("all threads done")
    '                                    End Sub)
    'Do Until (tasks(0).Status = 5 And tasks(0).Status = 5)
    '    Application.DoEvents()
    'Loop
    'Task.WaitAll(tasks)


    Parallel.For(0, 3, Sub(i)
    if i = 0 then
                           doSearch()
    elseif i = 1 then
                            doOtherSearch()
    end if
                               End Sub)
    checkWishlist()
End Sub


    Public Sub checkWishlist()
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In listview1.Items
        thisSelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM wishlist WHERE ID='" & lvi.SubItems(6).Text & "'"
        reader = thisSelectCommand.ExecuteReader
        If reader.HasRows = True Then
            lvi.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Else
            lvi.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If
        reader.Close()
    Next
End Sub


public sub doSearch()
for i as integer = 0 to 100
ListViewAddItem("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8")
next
End sub

public sub doOtherSearch()
for i as integer = 0 to 100
ListViewAddItem("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8")
next
End sub
```

Comment: Run the query in separate thread(or Task, whatever), then add them to listview in Main thread.

Comment: You mean i should run she sql query in the tasks and set the foreColor before using "ListViewAddItem" or?

Comment: You could use a SYNCLOCK but that will just slow you down. But it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background workers and wait for each task to finish before calling the next one like this:

```
Private worker_1 As new BackgroundWorker()
Private worker_2 As new BackgroundWorker()

AddHandler worker_1.DoWork, AddressOf worker_1_DoWork
AddHandler worker_1.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf worker_1_RunWorkerCompleted
AddHandler worker_2.DoWork, AddressOf worker_2_DoWork
AddHandler worker_2.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf worker_2_RunWorkerCompleted

' call the first task
worker_1.RunWorkerAsync()

Public Sub worker_1_DoWork() 
 ' do something here
End Sub

Public Sub worker_1_RunWorkerCompleted
  ' call the next task only after the first task is complete
  worker_2.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Public Sub worker_2_DoWork() 
 ' do something here
End Sub

Public Sub worker_2_RunWorkerCompleted
  ' call the next task
  ' and so on
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't this basicly be the same as Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll ? or does the runWorkerCompleted run in main thread (ui thread)? the thing is i want worker 1 & 2 to run parallel and then checkWishlist after that. so parallel for loop would do what i'm looking for as it waits for all threads to finnish before it continue. However if i understand correctly the delegate / invoke sub "queues" the ui updates, so checkWishlist is finnished before the ui has had time to add all items to listview.

Comment: If you have a race condition between two items running in the main thread, then you need to account for all situations by waiting for one of them to complete. If that mean putting them in separate threads, then maybe you should consider that. To answer your question, yes, the runWorkerCompleted runs in the main thread.